# Adding more sense to jquery auto suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, autosuggest

I have implemented jquery auto suggestions in my application which has a bunch of cities in it. The problem is it showing every strings which has the entered query. if i type `how` it shows all the strings which has 'how' in it in between..

The following is the list of results i get if i type `how` but i prefer to get it in a different order which i descrided and i don't want to show other results. I dont want to show other results.

```
Bhowra Bh
Chalk howa <--------------------------------This should come third
Chowka Ghat
Chowrigacha
Howbagh Jabalpur <--------------------------This should come first
Howrah <------------------------------------This should come second
Khowang
Ladhowal
Majhowalia
MHOW
Mhow
Mount Howrah <------------------------------This should come fourth
Pehowa Road
Pipalwali Chowki
Saheed Ishwar Chowdhary H
```

how do is make this work. here is the code i use.. or is there any other way to achieve this in javascript without jquery..?

```
$(".selector").autocomplete(/*parameters*/);
```

**NOTE: I use an array to store the city names and use them as source for auto complete. And i don't use AJAX**

Comment: You'd need to come up with an weighting algorithm which judges each matching value on if it is the same case, how close to the start of the value the match is found, and from your example, how long the value is.

Comment: How are you deciding the order? What is your criterion?

Comment: @juzerali The first and second starts with 'how' and the third and fourth has the second word starting with 'how'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i don't think this one needs a weighting algorithm. If i type 'how' strings starting with 'how' should come first...

Comment: Then why does `Chalk howa` come before `Mount Howrah`, and why should none of the other results be included?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan see their second word.. They have 'how' in the beginning.. so they are put in 3rd and 4th.. which is kinda look like weights to me.. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback to do the filtering and sorting yourself.

```
$(".selector").autocomplete(
  source: function(request, response) {
              // filter parameters based on request.term
              response(/*params*/, request.term);
          }
);
```

It's also possible to alter the search term at that point, but that wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: It's not ajax. Instead of using an array directly, this is a way to use a local function that can change the array and/or search term. It's a callback, but there is no ajax request involved.